# kableExtra how to use cell_spec from a user defined range?

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, kable

First, the package kableExtra indeed produces awesome table. I just have an additional request :

When running this example ( from the manual)

```
 iris[1:10, ] %>% select(-Species) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
          cell_spec(x, "latex", bold = T, color = spec_color(x, end = 0.9),
              font_size = spec_font_size(x))
        }) %>%
    kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = T, linesep = "", align = "c")
```

[image: cell_spec]

The cells are formated in each column. (1) How to adjust them to the entire table ? (2) Or to a user defined scale ? I noticed that both `kableExtra::spec_color` and
`kableExtra::cell_spec` make use of the `scales::rescale` function which does take a `from` argument but it's not used in the functions.

Below code of reproducible .Rnw script.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
<<tab10, echo=FALSE, results="as.is">>=
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
require(tidyverse)
@
<<tab1, echo=FALSE, results="as.is">>=
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
require(tidyverse)
iris[1:10, ] %>% select(-Species) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
          cell_spec(x, "latex", bold = T, color = spec_color(x, end = 0.9),
              font_size = spec_font_size(x))
        }) %>%
    kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = T, linesep = "", align = "c") 
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can add the `from` argument from rescale to the option list. It sounds like a great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, with the latest dev ver, you can use `scale_from` in `spec_color`, `spec_font_size` & `spec_angle`.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
iris[1:10, ] %>% 
  select(-Species) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
    cell_spec(x, "latex", bold = T, 
              color = spec_color(x, end = 0.9, scale_from = range(unlist(iris[1:10, ]))),
              font_size = spec_font_size(x, scale_from = range(unlist(iris[1:10, ]))))
  }) %>%
  kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = T, linesep = "", align = "c")
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just prints latex text, doesn't show the table in the "Viewer".